# Use Laravel Echo in jquery instead of VueJs

Tags: jquery, laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am facing an issue.

I've a linux setup on live server, 
I've `installed laravel-echo-server` which is working fine. also when I fire an `Event` 
It goes to the `redis-cli` and output the event which is being fired. then on `laravel-echo-server`. I see that the channel being connected and event being fired.

But when I try to do it on my client side in jQuery, it fails everytime.

`GET https://www.medeconsult.com.au:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Below is the code

```
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/laravel-echo-setup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    window.Echo.channel('user-notifications')
        .listen('.NotificationEvent', (data) => {
            i++;
            $("#notification").append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+i+'.'+data.title+'</div>');
            console.log(data);
        });
</script>
```

Below is the code for laravel-echo-setup.js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

There is a solution which suggests to use `NodeJs`.

I don't want to include `nodejs` because that is an extra backend server.

So I want to achieve this with the efficient approach.

Please suggest me how can I achieve it.

Or there is no way other than using NodeJs

Thanks

Comment: It might be worth having a look at: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use?

Comment: I am on laravel 7.x